# Animated splash screen using .gif

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I want to use animated **gif** for the Splash screen. So I change the `src` in config.xml into my gif like this:

```
...
<gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.gif" />
...
```

But when it runs, the gif image is **not animating** and only show the first frame.

I have another gif inside the app and it animates well. So I guess the one in splash screen is not `WebView`?

Is there a way to use gif for splash screen other than customizing the Android Java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In webview .gif works well. In other cases it does not work in android. You need to customize android java code to make it work. But their is an alternative.

If you have the images for all frames (you may also extract them from gif) and use android animation on the images. It will look like gif image only. All i mean is that you can do frame anmations.

This link will give you some idea:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-creating-frame-animations/

You may google more to find better tutorial. This kind animation works very well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If there's really no way to solve this without changing the auto-generated code, I would go with this one since it looks simple.

Comment: The other way is to use Movie as JaneGoodall mentioned above. There is no other way. Using .gif has potential problems, so google does not give default support. Using Frame animation is very simple and works perfect. I would recommend you to use that to avoid any potential problems of using .gif

Comment: happy to help. It will hardly take around 10 minutes to make it work :)

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use a `Movie` instead of a `WebView`. That class is not well-documented but someone was nice enough to make a walkthrough, albeit one that isn't specific to splash screens:

http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/

I'm not sure if this meets your "other than customizing the Android Java code" requirement, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm indeed looking for solution that doesn't require changing the auto-generated code. But if there's no other way, then I guess I have no choice.

Comment: If your requirement is "other than customizing autogenerated code" as opposed to "other than customizing any code" then this should do. You'll have to edit your normal code but you shouldn't have to edit R.java.

Comment: Sorry, I mean all the generated Android code from Phonegap. But I don't think there's a way to solve this without changing it.