# Splash screen with gif image using webview in android

Tags: android, webview, gif

I am newbie in android. I am trying to create a splash screen with .gif image using `webView` and I went through many tutorials and SO answers but I am still not clear about how to create a splash screen with .gif image using `webView` so can anyone briefly explain its parts?

Comment: Why do you want to use a gif and a webview? Do you need to show web based content? Can you please be a bit more specific in your question, also discuss what you've tried.

Comment: i tried to use webview cuz it supports gif image

Comment: A webview is a very heavy component to add to an application. Are you using gif because it's an animation? If not then convert it to PNG, this is the standard format. If it's an animation then the correct way would be to use a series of PNG images and animate them using an AnimationDrawable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html.

Comment: You can use image slide show. It works fine. Check that. Very basic issue ; [LINKISHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967817/animated-splash-screen-using-gif)