# Animated Splash screen Android

Tags: android

I want to show my animated gif image in full size on the splash screen, but it's not working. I also used `match parent`. Whats the problem here? My xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splashscreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.foodie.splash.splashscreen">


    <com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: its in only middle but i want in whole page]

Java code:

```
package com.example.foodie.splash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GifImageView gifImageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);

        gifImageView = (GifImageView)findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);

        //Set GIFImageView resource
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("foodie.gif");
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            gifImageView.setBytes(bytes);
            gifImageView.startAnimation();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {

        }

        //Wait for 3 seconds and start Activity Main
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                splashscreen.this.startActivity(new Intent(splashscreen.this,MainActivity.class));
                splashscreen.this.finish();
            }
        },5000); // 3000 = 3second



    }
}
```

Comment: I want this gif to show in  whole page like intro.pls help.

Comment: Show your java code where you are setting gif into gifView

Comment: @somumkhan : try android:scaleType="FIT_XY" instead of android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Comment: Rishabh Mahatha i attached java file above. take a look on that. thank you.

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` remove it Scales the image using CENTER https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: @somumkhan If you are using android:scaleType="FIT_XY" the gif will pixelate. You need to  create gif for every dimension --mdpi, hdpi etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated splash screen using .gif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967817/animated-splash-screen-using-gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you choose a wrong scale type, sett the scaleType as FitXY instead of fit center
but of course it lead to change the scales, find out if it has something like centerCrop scale.

```
<com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: can you tell me why you use `marginRight="0dp"` and `marginLeft="0dp"` in your answer?

Comment: @Charuka just for clarification, it's same as none